# Is there a way to summarize or condense TypeError checks for multiple arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have defined this constructor for a class to raise TypeErrors:

```
def __init__(self, name: str, author: str, quantity: int, price = 100):
    #Validate the received arguments
    if not isinstance(name, str):
        raise TypeError(f"The specified Name '{name}' is not a string!")
        
    if not isinstance(author, str):
        raise TypeError(f"The specified Author '{author}' is not a string!")
    
    if not isinstance(quantity,int):
        raise TypeError(f"The specified quantity '{quantity}' is not an int or float!")

    if not isinstance(price,int):
        raise TypeError(f"The specified quantity '{price}' is not an int or float!")
```

Is there a way to condense all of these isinstances? Or is there a better way to check and raise TypeErrors for multiple arguments? Because this method right now seems very clunky, especially if I have to initialize multiple attributes.

Comment: Fair warning: isinstance fails on floats when checking against int. float is not a subclass of int, I'm afraid. This is going to raise an error if price or quantity are floats. This illustrates a wider problem: in Python we typically use duck-typing: if it has the methods of a string, it's a string! We don't normally actually check types like this.

Comment: Please keep in mind that `isinstance(price,int)` will *not* pass for a `float`, and a type annotation like `: int` is *not* intended to accept a `float` (third-party static type checkers will complain). If you want a `float` to be acceptable then write the code accordingly; otherwise, adjust the error message.

Comment: I'm so sorry about that. I actually did correct the error message later on (I came across the issues both of you have mentioned) I just did not realize I had posted the faulty code snippet in the question. But thank you so much for your advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [@typechecked decorator](https://typeguard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide.html#using-the-decorator) from `typeguard`, which works with type hints.

```
from typeguard import typechecked

@typechecked
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, a: float, b: str):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    
MyClass(a='1', b='asdf')
```

This will return a TypeError:

> TypeError: type of argument "a" must be either float or int; got str instead

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [22], in <cell line: 9>()
      6         self.a = a
      7         self.b = b
----> 9 MyClass(a='1', b='asdf')

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/typeguard/__init__.py:1032, in typechecked.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
   1030 def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
   1031     memo = _CallMemo(python_func, _localns, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
-> 1032     check_argument_types(memo)
   1033     retval = func(*args, **kwargs)
   1034     try:

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/typeguard/__init__.py:875, in check_argument_types(memo)
    873             check_type(description, value, expected_type, memo)
    874         except TypeError as exc:  # suppress unnecessarily long tracebacks
--> 875             raise TypeError(*exc.args) from None
    877 return True

TypeError: type of argument "a" must be either float or int; got str instead
```